# Notepad++ Copy marked words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of text where I want to copy only the red marked words

[Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fTX9.jpg)

As regex I use (\w*\w*\w*\d*\d*\d\w*\w*)

Input:

philips **hd892747**

philips **2000**

keurig **k1500**

DeLonghi **ESAM04110S**

Output:

hd892747

2000

k1500

ESAM04110S

Comment: You must show an example of input and expected output (as text, not as an image). Also show us what regex you have tried.

Comment: Perhaps use replace with group 1 `^.*\h([^\W\d]*\d+\w+)$`  https://regex101.com/r/w8qNyh/1

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `.*?space`  replace with `nothing` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern uses multiple occurrences of repeating optional word chars and digits and a single digit.

You could match all before the last horizontal whitespace and capture in a group matching the last word chars that contain a digit.

In the replacement use `$1`

```
^.*\h([^\W\d]*\d\w*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\h` Match any char except a newline and a horizontal whitespace char
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\W\d]*` Match 0+ times a word char except a digit
  - `\d\w*` Match a digit and 0+ word chars
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTpHKM/1)

Comment: If I have an output like this "DeLonghi ESAM04110S ABC"
Which regex should I use to get this "ESAM04110S"?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^.*\h([^\W\d]*\d\w*)(?: [A-Z]+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/mjtnlZ/1